# Improving performance with a react modal where the component runs on every page

Tags: react.js, memoization

I have a simple cookie popup where the component technically runs on every page, giving the user the option to accept all or essential cookies. Once they accept an option, the popup no longer shows. However, I keep wondering whether many of the variables need to be memoised because the `CookiePopup` component itself renders on every page.

```
export const CookiePopup = () => {
    const { cookieConsentSet, setCookieConsent } = useContext<CookieContextType>(CookieContext);
    // note: cookieConsentSet just gets a consent cookie value (so is null or string)
    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [showMoreInfo, setShowMoreInfo] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const btnText = useMemo<string>(() => `${showMoreInfo ? 'Allow Essential' : 'Manage'} Cookies`, [showMoreInfo]);
    const descriptiveText = useMemo<string>(
        () => (showMoreInfo ? COOKIE_BANNER_MSG_DETAILED : COOKIE_BANNER_MSG_BRIEF),
        [showMoreInfo]
    );

    const openModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(true);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
        setShowMoreInfo(false);
    };

    const acceptCookies = () => {
        const expiryDate: Date = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)); // 1 year from now
        document.cookie = `cookieConsent=all; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()};`;
        setCookieConsent('all');
        closeModal();
    };

    const declineCookies = () => {
        const expiryDate: Date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)); // expires in 1 day
        document.cookie = `cookieConsent=essential; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()};`;
        setCookieConsent('essential');
        closeModal();
    };

    const manageCookies = () => {
        if (!showMoreInfo) {
            setShowMoreInfo(true);
            return;
        }
        declineCookies();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!cookieConsentSet) {
            openModal();
        }
    }, [cookieConsentSet]);

    if (cookieConsentSet) return null;

    return (
        <Modal
            style={NO_MODAL_OVERLAY}
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            className={styles.cookiePopup}
            contentLabel='Cookie Notification'
            portalClassName={styles.modalOverlayWrap} // cannot use overlayClassName
        >
            <div className={`${styles.content} ${showMoreInfo ? styles.expanded : ''}`}>
                {showMoreInfo && <h3>Cookie Preferences</h3>}
                <p>
                    {descriptiveText} <Link to='/cookie-policy'>Learn more</Link>
                </p>
                <div
                    className={`${styles.buttonsContainer} ${styles.spaced} ${styles.largeButtons} ${styles.cookieBtns} ${styles.specificity}`}
                >
                    <button onClick={acceptCookies} className={styles.btnPrimary}>
                        Allow All Cookies
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={manageCookies} className={styles.btnGrey}>
                        {btnText}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

I have a couple of questions in particular:

1. Am I correct in memoising the `btnText` and `descriptiveText` variales?
2. Should these functions also be memoised (with useCallback): `openModal`, `closeModal`, `acceptCookies`, `declineCookies` & `manageCookies`?

Presumably both should be memoised, otherwise they will be recreated on every page, even when the modal doesn't show up (if the user has already selected an option) because the component will still run.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `cookieConsentSet` is truthy you `return null;` and none of the other code matters.  You already know this by the second line of your code.  Of course you cannot just `return null;` on line 3 because that would violate the rules of hooks by making the remaining hook calls conditional.  But you *can* conditionally return a component.

My primary strategy here is to create an outer layer that checks `cookieConsentSet`.  That way you can avoid executing anything else if you don't need to.  If you were doing this sort of thing without using React contexts, then you would pass the `setCookieConsent` function from the outer component to the inner component via props.  In this case you don't need to pass any props because both components can access the context.

Separated components, without any other changes:

```
const InnerCookiePopup = () => {
    const { cookieConsentSet, setCookieConsent } = useContext<CookieContextType>(CookieContext);
    // note: cookieConsentSet just gets a consent cookie value (so is null or string)
    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [showMoreInfo, setShowMoreInfo] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const btnText = useMemo<string>(() => `${showMoreInfo ? 'Allow Essential' : 'Manage'} Cookies`, [showMoreInfo]);
    const descriptiveText = useMemo<string>(
        () => (showMoreInfo ? COOKIE_BANNER_MSG_DETAILED : COOKIE_BANNER_MSG_BRIEF),
        [showMoreInfo]
    );

    const openModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(true);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
        setShowMoreInfo(false);
    };

    const acceptCookies = () => {
        const expiryDate: Date = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)); // 1 year from now
        document.cookie = `cookieConsent=all; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()};`;
        setCookieConsent('all');
        closeModal();
    };

    const declineCookies = () => {
        const expiryDate: Date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)); // expires in 1 day
        document.cookie = `cookieConsent=essential; expires=${expiryDate.toUTCString()};`;
        setCookieConsent('essential');
        closeModal();
    };

    const manageCookies = () => {
        if (!showMoreInfo) {
            setShowMoreInfo(true);
            return;
        }
        declineCookies();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!cookieConsentSet) {
            openModal();
        }
    }, [cookieConsentSet]);


    return (
        <Modal
            style={NO_MODAL_OVERLAY}
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            className={styles.cookiePopup}
            contentLabel='Cookie Notification'
            portalClassName={styles.modalOverlayWrap} // cannot use overlayClassName
        >
            <div className={`${styles.content} ${showMoreInfo ? styles.expanded : ''}`}>
                {showMoreInfo && <h3>Cookie Preferences</h3>}
                <p>
                    {descriptiveText} <Link to='/cookie-policy'>Learn more</Link>
                </p>
                <div
                    className={`${styles.buttonsContainer} ${styles.spaced} ${styles.largeButtons} ${styles.cookieBtns} ${styles.specificity}`}
                >
                    <button onClick={acceptCookies} className={styles.btnPrimary}>
                        Allow All Cookies
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={manageCookies} className={styles.btnGrey}>
                        {btnText}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

```
export const CookiePopup = () => {
    const { cookieConsentSet } = useContext<CookieContextType>(CookieContext);

    if (cookieConsentSet) return null;

    return (
        <InnerCookiePopup/>
    );
};
```

---

As far as memoization, there's not a lot of state changes or expensive computations happening here.  Filling a string template is trivial and the ternary in `descriptiveText` is even more trivial.  I would use `React.memo` to memoize the inner component as a whole.  Yes your function will still get re-initialized when the component state changes and yes you could use `useCallback`, but it's probably overkill.

It's more important to make sure that the `setCookieConsent` function in your `CookieContext` is memoized so that you don't have unnecessary re-renders in the components that use this context.

---

I'm not understanding the need for the `useEffect`.  It seems like you could just have the initial state of the modal be open.  But I could be missing something.  Maybe it's needed for a UI effect of opening the modal.

I'm also not loving that you set the `document.cookie =`  property from inside your modal component.  It's only executed inside callback functions so it's not a huge problem, but you might consider handling that through some other hook or component related to your `CookieContext`.

This modal covers both the "Manage Cookies" and the "Accept Cookies" situations.  It's very confusing to me that you still display a `<button onClick={manageCookies}>` even when we are in "Manage Cookies" mode.  It seems like the button acts differently?  So then I don't think it should be co-mingled in this way.  Maybe have separate buttons that are conditionally rendered?  Maybe have a separate `ModalUI` component and pass down `buttonLabel` and `onClickButton` props?  There's definitely more that can be cleaned up here.

This replaces your `btnText` and `manageCookies` and, to me, feels more readable and understandable.

```
{showMoreInfo ? (
  <button onClick={declineCookies} className={styles.btnGrey}>
    Allow Essential Cookies
  </button>
) : (
  <button onClick={() => setShowMoreInfo(true)} className={styles.btnGrey}>
    Manage Cookies
  </button>
)}
```